# Docker: skygear server not starting, connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, connection-refused, skygear

I followed the Docker manual on https://docs.skygear.io/server/guide/getting-started-docker.
I used Kitematic to download Skygear Server from SkygearIO.
When the server tries to start it can't connect to a database.

```
ERRO[0001] Unable to begin transaction for schema migration: dial tcp
[::1]:5432: getsockopt: connection refused  logger=skydb
ERRO[0001] Failed to start skygear: failed to open connection: skydb/pq: 
unable to connect to database because of a network error = dial tcp 
[::1]:5432: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: attach code where you run your containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the [Setup Skygear Development Server Locally](https://docs.skygear.io/guides/advanced/server/).